# Find the path has specified length on the 2d matrix

Tags: graph, path

I have a problem about algorithm. 
Given 2d matrix such:

`2,   1,   2,   5,   5,   0
1,   4,   0,   1,   0,   8
2,   8,   4,   1,   7,   1
5,   6,   4,   9,   7,   9
8,   7,   9,   6,   2,   5
6,   6,   7,   4,   8,   3`

Question: use "up", "left", "right", "down" moving to find path has length is 10 (can't revisit a node).
Example:

`2,   1,   2,   5,   5,   0
1,   4,   0,  [1],  0,   8
2,   8,   4,  [1], [7], [1]
5,   6,   4,   9,   7,   9
8,   7,   9,   6,   2,   5
6,   6,   7,   4,   8,   3`

More specifically, the algorithm needs to answer the question: exist or not exist such a way

Comment: Welcome to [*Stackoverflow*](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), we don't do other people's hw here.

Comment: Update your question with what you have already tried :), and one more question, can we revisit a node?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by dividing into 2 small problems:

- subset sum problem
- check path exists through a set of nodes